# Create folding with several starting markers

Tags: folding

I can create code folding in marker based folding if there is only one starting marker and one ending marker. What if I have to fold a code which has two starting marker and only one ending marker?

For example in the following code I am able to fold either `ifdef` or `ifndef` but not both.

Vim commands:

```
set foldmarker=`ifdef,`endif
set foldmethod=marker
```

Code:

```
ifdef
     /*
      * some code
      */
ifndef
     /*
      * some code
      */
endif
     /*
      * some code
      */
endif
```

Answer (score 2):

I've done that for C & C++ in [VimFold4C](https://github.com/LucHermitte/VimFold4C) -- along with folding brackets, includes, comments... However, there is a pending bug regarding nested #ifdef.

The task is not that trivial. That's why I won't post code here.

If you're just interested in folding those, may be, the easier would be to hack the syntax file of your language and indicate that folding shall occur on those "markers" -- and then use the syntax folding method.

Comment: Thanks Luc..!!
Anything like VimFold4C will be too much for me.. !!
I will try with fold-by-syntax method.

Answer (score 1):

Fortunately, your desired markers have a common prefix, so you could use:

```
set foldmarker=if,endif
```

Then it will catch both `ifdef` and `ifndef`. By default, vim's 'foldtext' displays the line excluding the marker (leaving just `5 lines: def`) so you could define a custom one:

```
function! FoldlineText()
    return getline(v:foldstart)
endfun
set foldtext=FoldlineText()
```

That will look like this (`set foldcolumn=3` so you can see the folding):
[image: showing question code partially folded]

The downside is if you also have `if` logic with different delimiters (like C++'s `if` vs `#if`), then those get folded too.

For languages like C++ that have characters distinguishing the different kinds of `if`s, we can resolve that ambiguity:

```
set foldmarker=#if,#endif
```

[image: cpp code showing the if is not folded]

From the `2` in the foldcolumn, you can see that the stink block is not folded.